# MSSQL 2008 getting results of concatenated fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a category table, where in one column i have a list of fields from the data table.

The task is to make query of the data table, where i should display the fields based on the field list definition in the category table.

the category table looks like

`CATEGID | FIELDLIST
1        |[Field1]+':'+[Field2]+':'+[Field3]
2        |[Field3]+':'+[Field1]`

data table looks like

`DATAID | CATEGID | FIELD1 | FIELD2  | FIELD3
1       |   1     |value1  | value21 | value32
2       |   1     |value12 | value20 | value31
3       |   2     |value15 | value2  | value35
4       |   2     |value10 | value25 | value3
5       |   1     |value19 | value20 | value36
6       |   2     |value17 | value2  | value36`

as the result i would like something like this

`DATAID | CATEGID | FIELD1 | FIELD2  | FIELD3  | CONCATENATED_RESULT
1       |   1     |value1  | value21 | value32 | value1:value21:value32
2       |   1     |value12 | value20 | value31 | value12:value20:value31
3       |   2     |value15 | value2  | value35 | value35:value15
4       |   2     |value10 | value25 | value3  | value3:value10
5       |   1     |value19 | value20 | value36 | value19:value20:value36
6       |   2     |value17 | value2  | value36 | value36:value17`

thanks for your hint!

Comment: Somebody should get a  prize for that db design.Joke aside,I think you need dynamic sql for this.

Comment: You need [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: Are you able to change the schema at all? I would store your field list differently.

Comment: Thanks for you all for the answers. I know this is not easy, that's why I asked. Actually this is a real need, however the fieldlist definition as I presented in the category table is already the result in a view. Normally every field is stored in a separate row in another table related to the category table with CATEGID. But as the requirement user wants to see the data in one field as a concatenated values based on the field list definition per category.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not even sure creative use of [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001(v=sql.100).aspx) can save us here. You could theoretically construct a sql string with FIELDLIST as a parameter but how would you join on that such that the field list and thus your output would change?

A bizarre schema calls for a degenerate solution. Enter [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx).

```
select d.DATAID, d.CATEGID, d.FIELD1, d.FIELD2, d.FIELD3, 
       REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(c.FIELDLIST, 
           '[Field1]', d.FIELD1), 
           '[Field2]', d.FIELD2), 
           '[Field3]', d.FIELD3), 
           '+''', ''), '''+', '')
from DATA d
inner join CATEGORY c on c.CATEGID = d.CATEGID
```

I sincerely hope that this is a thought exercise and not an actual schema used by real people.